# Wikidata query equivalent in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to transform my SPARQL query from Wikidata to DBpedia (just for educational purpose), but it doesn't work. Could someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

In http://query.wikidata.org

```
SELECT ?musician ?musicianLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
    ?musician wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
    ?musician wdt:P136 ?genre .
    FILTER(?genre IN (wd:Q383982, wd:Q206159))
}
GROUP BY ?musician ?musicianLabel
ORDER BY ASC(?musicianLabel)
```

*working*

... and in http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql

```
SELECT ?musician WHERE {
    ?musician a <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Person> .
    ?musician <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Genre> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Genre> .
    FILTER(<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Genre> IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_Pop>, <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_Rock>))
}
GROUP BY ?musician
ORDER BY ASC(?musician)
```

*not working*

Comment: I see three issues: 1.) schema entities (classes and properties) have `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` as namespace 2.) properties do start with small letter, i.e. `genre` and 3) you have for some reason replaced the variable `?genre` by a resource.

Comment: and what is the purpose of `group by` in your queries?

Comment: ah, and the genres are `Psychedelic_rock` and `Psychedelic_pop` - there is a redirect from both resources you used, but you'll get only 4 results then without resolving the redirects

Comment: `SELECT ?musician WHERE {
    ?musician a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
    ?musician <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?genre .
    FILTER(?genre IN (<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_pop>, <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock>))
}

ORDER BY ASC(?musician)`

Comment: Thank you @AKSW for the explanation. 
`->` 3) was actually not intended by me.
`->` What do you mean by "redirect"?
`->` I used `GROUP BY` because of double entries. i.e. Person `http://dbpedia.org/page/Cam_Avery` has genre Psychedelic_Rock *and* Psychedelic Pop and therefore would appear twice in the result list

Comment: Also note that `http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql` is not the same as `http://dbpedia.org/sparql`, though both are powered by Virtuoso, and similar DBpedia data is loaded into both. The LOD Cloud Cache has much more data than the DBpedia datasets loaded, and results here may differ widely from what you get elsewhere.

Comment: With redirects I mean: In DBpedia you have some kind of synonyms for the same entity like in Wikipedia. All of those redirect to a single RDF resources that contains all the data then to avoid redundant data. And DBpedia just reflects the Wikipedia entries.

Comment: For example, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_Rock` exists as RDF resource as does `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock`. The former has a `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects` triple to the latter. In the browser this happens automatically via HTTP 303 see other, so you'll always get the HTML rendered by using the RDF data of `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock`. In SPARQL on the other hand, this isn't done because it's not a concept of the query language.

Comment: Some DBpedia resources still use the redirected resource, you can check with `describe <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_Rock>` query

Comment: Regarding `group by` - the correct operation to avoid duplicates is `distinct`, i.e. `select distinct ?musician`

Comment: Good hint, @TallTed, thanks

Comment: @AKSW regarding redirects: Got it, thanks. So, does it mean that if you want to use a resource for SPARQL queries, you first have to check if it is the "correct" URI by using the `describe` query? i.e. on the endpoint `http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql` I do `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_Rock>` which has a redirect to `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock>, or i could also do `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock>` and it tells me that the redirect is to the same URI so this is the correct URI to use.

Comment: well, either check via `DESCRIBE` query or simply put the URL in the browser, it will always redirect you to the RDF resource that contains the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you dropped the label from your adapted query...  Try [this](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fmusician+%3Fmusicianlabel+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A+%7B+%3Fmusician+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.+%0D%0A+++%3Fmusician+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fgenre%3E+%3Fgenre+.%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fmusician+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fmusicianlabel+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++FILTER+%28+LANGMATCHES+%28+LANG+%28+%3Fmusicianlabel+%29%2C+%27en%27+%29+%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A+++FILTER+%28%3Fgenre+IN+%28+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPsychedelic_pop%3E+%2C+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPsychedelic_rock%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++%29%0D%0A++++++++++%29%0D%0A+%7D+%0D%0AORDER+BY+ASC+%28+%3Fmusician+%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) ([results](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fmusician+%3Fmusicianlabel+%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A+%7B+%3Fmusician+a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPerson%3E+.+%0D%0A+++%3Fmusician+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fgenre%3E+%3Fgenre+.%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fmusician+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23label%3E+%3Fmusicianlabel+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++FILTER+%28+LANGMATCHES+%28+LANG+%28+%3Fmusicianlabel+%29%2C+%27en%27+%29+%29+%0D%0A++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A+++FILTER+%28%3Fgenre+IN+%28+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPsychedelic_pop%3E+%2C+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FPsychedelic_rock%3E%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++%29%0D%0A++++++++++%29%0D%0A+%7D+%0D%0AORDER+BY+ASC+%28+%3Fmusician+%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+))

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?musician ?musicianlabel 
WHERE
 { ?musician a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> . 
   ?musician <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/genre> ?genre .
   OPTIONAL { ?musician <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?musicianlabel . 
              FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG ( ?musicianlabel ), 'en' ) ) 
            }
   FILTER (?genre IN ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_pop> , 
                       <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock>
                     )
          )
 } 
ORDER BY ASC ( ?musician )
```

Comment: Great, thank you @TallTed. I dropped the label on the dbpedia query because I didn't know how to do it ;-)

Comment: `DISTINCT` is missing to avoid duplicates when people have both genres, e.g. `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barbara_Robison`

Comment: Is there a difference between using `FILTER` and `VALUES`? Both seem to do the same. So in the above query, one could remove the `FILTER` and therefore add `VALUES (?genre) { ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_pop> ) ( <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychedelic_rock> ) }`

Comment: @RoRu - Speed may vary between the two. In this case, not by much. (I did notice that you lose 4 musicians by not including the `_Pop` and `_Rock` genre variants, so you probably want to tweak things further, anyway...)

Comment: I have a follow up on that :-) would be great if you guys TallTed and @AKSW would help again - you already did help me sparql-novice a lot, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220599/faceted-sparql-query-in-dbpedia-and-wikidata-few-questions